# Get karaf env variables inside camelContext

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I am trying to get karaf env variables inside camelContext
I have added

`<ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$[" placeholder-suffix="]"/>`

outside camelcontext and tried to use the karaf.home inside camelcontext. But its failing load the data from that location. I've tried like this

`<camelContext id="_camelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<propertyPlaceholder id="config" location="file:$[karaf.home]/etc/application_config.prope‌​rties" />
</camelContext>`

Can't we access it inside camelcontext?

Comment: I am not sure if that will work. You can access normal environment variables though via @PropertyInject annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Karaf variables are defined as JVM system variables, not env variables.
What do you need them for?
If you just need to load a config file, use the OSGi approach and **do not directly reference any path**.

```
<blueprint>
    <cm:property-placeholder id="yourConfig"
                             persistent-id="file.name" />

    <camelContext>
        <propertyPlaceholder location="blueprint:yourConfig" />

        <!-- Access properties using {{property.name}} -->
        <route id="One" autoStartup="{{route.one.enabled}}" > ...
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

This will load properties from `${karaf.home}/etc/file.name.cfg`.
And your bundle can run inside other containers too.

Comment: I have tried this option I am able to get the properties data in camelContext but not in routeContext.

Comment: I cannot give more details without seeing your code

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in different manuals, post and so on if you trying to use environment variables **inside  tag** you should **use {{var}}** instead of ${var}. You could use {{karaf.home}} or {{karaf.root}} or {{karaf.etc}}.

IMPORTANT: if you OCCASIONALLY have formatting symbols in file path \r (i.e. C:\receive.cfg), \n path evaluation works incorrect, symbols escape is not supported in Camel therefore the only way - is to edit filenames.

Part of my blueprint:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
        <from .../>
        <setBody>
            <method ref="dbExtractorBean" method="extract(true, '{{karaf.home}}\etc\com.mycopmany.extraction.cfg')"/>
        </setBody>
        <to .../>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It is possible to see env values:

- karaf@root>shell:env karaf.base
- karaf@root>shell:env karaf.home

This config is for my develop Windows machine, on Linux you should use / for path separation, i don't know (on this moment) how to configure path separator to make this route works both on Windows and Linux machines without recompile.